# Magento API customer.create -> cart_product.moveToCustomerQuote

Tags: cart, customer, api, quote, create

I created a User using the Magento API.
I then created a shopping cart and want to move this cart to the created costumer, but this errors as **Customer's quote does not exist**.

Moving the cart to an existing customer works fine!
If I login to the API created customer once and move the cart with its CustomerId it works too.

So is there an solution to create the Customer's quote over the API?

Answer (score 0):

After you create a customer shopping cart you get a quote id / shopping cart id .There is now way to move this quote ID to a new session id (obtained after creating a new customer profile in this case) but you can always create a new shopping cart again and copy all the items to the new shopping cart id.

EDIT UPDATE CORRECTION:
it seems there is a api to do move a customer cart

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.moveToCustomerQuote.html